# How to get the best images from a Wikimedia Commons category?

Tags: api, images, wikimedia-commons

Wikimedia Commons had tons of images of all qualities, sorted in categories.

The best images are sometimes awarded a "featured" badge, or a "quality" or "valued" badge.
The majority of images have no badge at all.

**Question**: How to get the best images from a given category, including its sub-categories?

- Users will casually enter categories such as "[Butterflies](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Butterflies)", which has hundreds of sub-categories containing tens of thousands of files. Despite this, the results must come within 10 seconds.
- The API has to be available online (95% uptime or best)
- Picture quality is readily available through the featured/quality/vales badges, but I am open to other objective and subjective quality measurements.
- Ideally the API should return all images from in decreasing order of quality, with paging so that the data starts to come as fast as possible.